# wordpress redirects me to subdirectory folder

Tags: wordpress

I have wordpress installed in subdirectory folder named "thumbs". I also followed the steps [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory).

Everything works fine but if I go to `www.mysite.com/wp-admin` it redirects me to `www.mysite.com/thumbs/wp-admin`, I don't want that to happen because I want the subdirectory folder to be secret.

So what I want is if I visit or somebody visit www.mysite.com/wp-admin I want the wordpress 404 error page to display. Thanks in advance for the help.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your root `.htaccess` (not `thumbs/.htaccess`) file to add a rule for `wp-admin`, e.g. :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: still don't work for me. originally i don't see any .htaccess file but if i change my permalink to postname or anything .htaccess will appear. i added the rule for wp-admin but still don't work. thank you for the reply.

Comment: by the way i change the subdirectory folder to thumbsup, it redirect me to this url if i'm not log-in http://royale-shop.com/thumbsup/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Froyale-shop.com%2Fthumbsup%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

Comment: This should work (tested when I wrote the answer), did you really modify `/.htaccess`, and not `/thumbsup/.htaccess` ?

Comment: yeah i modified /.htaccess and not the /thumbsup/.htaccess but still it redirect me to www.mysite.com/thumbsup/wp-admin, i have no idea whats going on and i know that it should work also. Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HTACCESS with this code

```
# Switch rewrite engine off in case this was installed under HostPay.
RewriteEngine Off

SetEnv DEFAULT_PHP_VERSION 53

DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```